# How to create a web template editor with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, editor, builder

I'm pretty new to rails, and i'm trying to build a web template editor in rails where users can come in and create their websites without having any programming knowledge.

something similar to:
 
http://imcreator.com/
muse.adobe.com
www.wix.com
www.squarespace.com

I'm wondering if there are any gems or plugins
I was also told that i should look for a control library? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of CMS kits like [Refinery](http://refinerycms.com/), [Radiant](http://radiantcms.org/), or you can use something like [Comfortable Mexican Sofa](http://thechangelog.com/post/3293511232/comfortable-mexican-sofa-comfortablemexicansofa-is-a-tin) which is maintained by an associate of mine.

Building a CMS isn't especially tricky, but getting a good general-purpose one built can be fussy.

Comment: thank you for the comment @tadman i'm wondering if a CMS is what i need for this project. i'll look at the resources you provided

Comment: Whatever platform you pick, you're going to have to do a lot of work to convert it into a product like that. You might want to use these CMS kits as examples more than as a foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Would a CMS work for this?  Like RefineryCMS.com?

I'm going to be doing this too - but will be taking another approach.  More of a 'showcase/showroom' direction where the templates are pre-made but they can upload artwork and change content.

Anyhow - good luck!